# Processar Dados rs232

Tags: c#, .net, serial, api

boa tarde!

preciso de uma ajuda que seria mais uma explicação de certa forma.

estou fazendo homologação de um equipamento que enviar dados via rs232 no entanto o equipamento não tem um protocolo que possa auxiliar informando a ordem dos dados e etc somente um appendix de Host slave. eu queria só entender o processo de processamento de dados rs232 em C#. vamos lá:

esses são os dados que recebo no meu gateway:

```
33463031313033443031313130313131
35423638333035443542363733303544
53696E676C6520576569676874303332
35303F3F3F3F2E546F74616C20576569
6768743A303030333235306B672E3031
31303031313030313130303131303031
3130
```

Em `ASCII` fica da seguinte maneira: `3F01103D011101115B68305D5B67305DSingle Weight03250????.Total Weight:0003250kg.01100110011001100110`

Porém no appendix informa que os dados são do tipo Long, Atributte R, e o comando é HEX 03. Não sei se consegui ser claro se meu fonte onde trabalho os dados:

```
var rs232 = aAux[it++];

int desloc = 0;
int _base = 0;
var balanca = ASCIItoHex(rs232);
byte[] fadiga = BitHandler.GetBytes(rs232, BytesFormatInput.ASCII);

var weight = new WeightPro();

weight.Ativo = (ulong)fadiga[desloc + _base + 1] << 00;
weight.Ativo |= (ulong)fadiga[desloc + _base + 2]<< 08;
weight.Ativo |= (ulong)fadiga[desloc + _base + 3]<< 16;
weight.Position = fadiga[desloc + _base + 2];
weight.DateTime = fadiga[desloc + _base + 3];
weight.Usuario = fadiga[desloc + _base + 4];
weight.Produto = fadiga[desloc + _base + 5];
weight.Placa = fadiga[desloc + _base + 6];
weight.TotalWeight = fadiga[desloc + _base + 7];
weight.Weight = fadiga[desloc + _base + 8];
weight.Record = fadiga[desloc + _base + 9];

Base.System.SystemEventManager.Instance.WriteLine(weight.ToString());
```

Resultado na tela:

```
Properties Weight Pro
Ativo:3158320
Position:49
DateTime:48
Usuario:51
Produto:49
Placa:48
TotalWeight:48
Weight:48
Record:48
```

Comment: bom pessoal, se alguém puder me ajudar. esses dados que mencionei acima são o protocolo modbus ASCII, pesquisei bastante sobre esse protocolo porém ainda não entendi como realiza a leitura do mesmo. se puderem me dar uma luz, ficarei grato.